# Ant change directory name

Tags: ant, scripting

I want to rename folder that starts with jdbc_****.
    Because some script generate folder like jdbc_210, jdbc_344.
    So I want to rename such foldeers with single name jdbc.

```
I am new to it, please advise and excuse my for bad tag coding.

<move todir="${../sbcdomain/config/jdbc}">
    <fileset dir="${../sbcdomain/config/jdbc_}"/>
</move>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `<move>` task uses a [`<regexpmapper>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper) to rename the "jdbc" directories.

```
<move todir="${out.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${out.dir}"/>
    <!-- Explanation of the following regular expression mapper -->
    <!-- (.*)  : capturing group 1 -->
    <!-- \b    : matches the word boundary at the start of the "jdbc*" directory name -->
    <!-- jdbc_ : matches the literal characters "jdbc_" -->
    <!-- \d+   : matches the digits after "jdbc_" -->
    <!-- (.*)  : capturing group 2 -->
    <regexpmapper from="(.*)\bjdbc_\d+(.*)" to="\1jdbc\2"/>
</move>
```

Comment: I dont understand it completely...
What i have to mention in ${out.dir}

Comment: Replace ${out.dir} with whatever directory you want.

Comment: still unable to ... can we discuss on gmail chat